# UIsegmentedControl title appearance

Tags: ios, user-interface, uisegmentedcontrol

[image]

HI, i set my uisegmentedcontrol's width manually, but when the width gets too small, the words becomes ...

Is that anyway that it won't behave in this way? Instead, i just want to show the text just like the picture shown below.

[image]

Comment: try doing `segmentedControl.apportionsSegmentWidthsByContent = true`

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest changing your design here and going for a different approach.

The design that you seem to want makes readability pretty much impossible.

Plus, what happens if I'm using your app and add another "Active Project". What happens if I have 10 active projects?

Take the fact that the UI does not work as a sign that you are using the wrong UI for the problem you are trying solve.

I'd suggest possibly just have the current project title here with a button to maybe present a list of projects to switch to... or something.

Answer (score 0):

The text has been truncated. If you want it to fit your segment, you need to update the segment control size based on the text length. If you just want to get rid of truncation, you can use the following snippet. However, it's not recommended, as later Apple might change the `UISegmentControl` hierarchy.

```
    for item in segmentedControl.subviews {
        for subview in item.subviews {
            if subview.isKind(of: UILabel.self) {
                let _label = subview as! UILabel                    
                _label.numberOfLines = 0
                _label.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
            }
        }
    }
```